# asp.net MVC webgrid with grouping

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

Can somebody help me in following view via webgrid

```
username    location    Date
a           abc         12/10/2017
a           def     ↑   12/10/2017
a           def         12/10/2017
a           def         12/11/2016
c           abc         12/10/2017





username    location    Date
a           abc         12/10/2017
a           def     ↓   12/10/2017
a           def         12/11/2016
c           abc         12/10/2017
```

I have make the group on username/location and Date field in my object list. But not able to make above view

I am trying following

```
 @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: false, rowsPerPage: 5, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
        <div id="gridContent">
            @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                headerStyle: "header",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                selectedRowStyle: "select",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("Email", "User Name"),
                    grid.Column("location", "location"),
                    grid.Column("AccessedOn", "Date"),
                    grid.Column(format: (item) =>
                    {

                        if (item.count > 1)
                        {
                            WebGrid subGrid = new WebGrid(source: item.x);
                            return subGrid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                                headerStyle: "header",
                                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                                selectedRowStyle: "select",
                                columns: grid.Columns(
                                    grid.Column("Email", null),
                                    grid.Column("location", null),
                                    grid.Column("AccessedOn", null))
                                );
                        }
                        else
                            return null;
                    }
                        )
                    ))



        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like this

```
a=>a.GroupBy(a.username).groupBy(a.location).tolist()
```

Comment: Group object list is already ready. i just needed help in webgrid usage

Comment: can you please mention the version and library name of webgrid you are using ?

Comment: Using Asp.net MVC 5